# How to force uppercase on a Html.TextboxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to force uppercase on a textbox in my view. So when user type something in the textbox, either the text is immediately converted in uppercase or (an alternative) the text is converted in uppercase when the form is submitted and the model is populated with data (in the action controller). Maybe there are some CSS or jquery solutions but I prefer some MVC solutions (if possible).

Here is my view:

```
@model Domain.Entities.ProjectTechnology

<script src="../../Scripts/Admin/_AddProjectTechnology.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="editor-label">Technologies</div>    

<div class="editor-field">

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_AddProjectTechnology", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST",
                                                                  UpdateTargetId = "RemoveProjectTechnology",
                                                                  InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                                  OnComplete = "AddProjectTechnologyCompleted" })) {    
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProjectID)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TechnologyID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TechnologyID)          
    }
</div>
```

And here is my model:

```
public class ProjectTechnology
{
    public int     ProjectID   { get; set; }
    public string  TechnologyID    { get; set; }
}
```

The textbox in question is this line: **@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TechnologyID)**

How can I proceed ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could perform this conversion on the getter of the property:

```
public class ProjectTechnology
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    private string _technologyId;
    public string TechnologyID 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_technologyId))
            {
                return _technologyId;
            }
            return _technologyId.ToUpper();
        }
        set
        {
            _technologyId = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I saw this solution on another post but I was not really satisfied with that because I think that this solution complicates my model, don't you think? What about **[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode=true, ...** in the model? But I don't know if we can force uppercase in that way? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bronzato, you can use CSS to force uppercase on the client but the user agent will post the actual lowercase value. So if it is only for visual purposes CSS is a possibility but if you want to  actual have an uppercase value you need to manually perform this conversion somewhere. You could have used `DisplayFormat` but that will only be useful for displaying the value on the client. When the user types some new characters they will be lowercase and when the form is submitted you will get lowercase.

Comment: If upper case is a business rule, then I would ToUpper in set only.

Comment: @PauloAbreu, we are talking about a view model here. Right @Bronzato? `ProjectTechnology` is not anything that is ever passed to your domain logic? It's a view model specifically designed for the given view. When we map this view model back to the original domain model in the mapping layer there will be no problems with the getter.

Comment: Darin I am not so sure since @Bronzato states model Domain.Entities.ProjectTechnology, anyway, as I told ... if this is a business rule: it will store the correct value, and we usually use more get than set.

Comment: @PauloAbreu, I don't know what he states, but @Bronzato should never pass any domain model to the view. So actually inside an ASP.NET MVC view you should never have `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomeProperty)` where the model is a domain model. In ASP.NET MVC only view models should be passed to views. Also controller action should only take view models from views. If you are passing domain models to your views you will be having far more serious design problems with the application than some uppercase letters :-)

Comment: @Darin, PauloAbreu: ProjectTechnology is a domain model in my case. I tought that I can pass a domain model to my view if this is what I need in my view. I tought that a ViewModel is passed to a view only if necessary (example: need some mix of attributes)... So I was wrong, I refactor my view model immediately. (I'm learning so I do a lot of mistakes).

Comment: This would lead us to another discussion. Nevertheless I do not follow the same receipt for every task. For some projects, using the model directly is enough for the task, for others may not be.

Answer (score 21):

The easiest way is IMO:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TechnologyID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @style = "text-transform:uppercase" } })
```

Comment: `text-transform`  will only change the appearance to CAPS. You will have to do manual transformation to uppercase on server side.

Comment: @Hemal true and it is better to attack this problem both on client and server.

Comment: You can use `toUpperCase()` on client side also.

Answer (score 6):

My line of code in the view is:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BldgNameAbbv, new {onkeyup="InputToUpper(this);"})
```

The associated script is:

```
<script>
function InputToUpper(obj)
{
    if (obj.value!="")
    {
    obj.value = obj.value.toUpperCase();
    }
}
</script>
```

This worked for me.  And using TextBoxFor, instead of EditorFor, was essential.

Comment: Old answer, but don't do this as it resets the caret (user's input position) which is really nasty if you're trying to edit the value.

Answer (score 6):

For EditorFor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => 
    model.Nome, 
    new { 
        htmlAttributes = new { 
            @class = "form-control", 
            @onkeyup = "InputToUpper(this);"
        } 
    }
)
```

Comment: Yup. It's a beautiful day outside and the birds are singing and babys laughing. All is well in my world thanks to this answer. I mean, who saves state abbreviations in lower case, ever?

Answer (score 4):

Also see this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TechnologyID, 
      new { @class = "whatever-class",  
      @style = "text-transform:uppercase"})
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :-). To improve your answer you should add some explanation.

Comment: Welcome to SOF.  Your answer was explained well by presenting the text-transform:uppercase style.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [text-transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp): uppercaase css property. If you want to make this from mvc, you can try create template for textbox(where you output input with css class for uppercase) and use UIHint attribute in the model. Hope this help you.

Comment: text-transform will only change the appearance to CAPS. You will have to do manual transformation to uppercase on server side

Answer (score 3):

I looked at changing my getter and settter in my Model but in my case I am using DB first so if I make a change to my db structure I would have to put the getter and setter code back every time.  This would be hard for us to manage in future.

I tried;

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Lname, 
  new { @class = "whatever-class",  
  @style = "text-transform:uppercase"})
```

but as stated above this only makes it capital on the View.  When you save it to the DB the data appears how ever the user entered it.(GIGO) For our site I am needing it to be upper case in the DB as well.  So what I did to solve this issue was to set the property of my object to itself along with .upper(), on the post action method Ex:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Recid,FName,LName")] UserModel change)
    {
        change.LName = change.LName.ToUpper();
        change.FName = change.FName.ToUpper();
        .... //code to update table
    }
```

So combined with the CSS style on the front end and setting the property in the post I have upper cases on both the Front and Back end.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply prevent saving to the DB as lower case then the most straight forward option is to alter the value to upper case during the HttpPost of the Create and Edit Actions
e.g.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ProjectID, TechnologyID ")] ProjectTechnology projectTechnology)
    {
        ProjectTechnology.TechnologyID = ProjectTechnology.TechnologyID.ToUpper();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(person);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: This also works and I also implemented @leifbattermann answer.